# Map is not visible, google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to make a buffer/a circle around any point clicked on the marker. The code which I followed was https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/587199/Draw-Cirlce-Around-Marker-in-Google-Map. I have referred the previously asked questions relating to these but could not find satisfactory answer.  I request all those who can answer to please share since this will help a lot. Thanks in advance. I have added the script file which is showing the error.

```
     <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/jquery-3.2.1%20(2).js">     </script>
         <script>
         var map;
         var circle;
         var marker;

     var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.06368, 72.53135);  
     function loadMap() {
         setLatLongValue();
         var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.06368, 72.53135);   
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             zoom: 16,
             center: currentlatlng,   
             mapTypeId: 'terrain',
             mapTypeControl: true,
             navigationControl: true
         });

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
             position: currentlatlng,  
             draggable: true,
             map: map
         });

     }

     function setLatLongValue() {
         jQuery('#txtPointA1').val(currentlatlng.lat());//#txtPointA1
         jQuery('#txtPointA2').val(currentlatlng.lng());

     }
     marker.addListener('click', function (event) {
         drawCircle(event.latLng);
     });
     function drawCircle() {

         if (circle != undefined)
             circle.setMap(null);

         var radius = 200;

         if (jQuery('#txtPointB1').val() != '' && !isNaN(jQuery('#txtPointB1').val()) && parseInt(jQuery('#txtPointB1').val()) > 0) {
             radius = parseInt(jQuery('#txtPointB1').val());
         }
         jQuery('#txtPointB1').val(radius.toString());

         var options = {
             strokeColor: '#800000',
             strokeOpacity: 1.0,
             strokeWeight: 1,
             fillColor: '#C64D45',
             fillOpacity: 0.5,
             map: map,
             center: currentlatlng,
             radius: radius
         };

         circle = new google.maps.Circle(options);
     } 

     $(window).load(function () {

         loadMap();
         setLatLongValue();
                      drawCircle();
     });
            //$(document).ready(function () {
            //    loadMap();
            //    setLatLongValue();
            //    //setMarker();
            //    drawCircle();
            //});
</script>
    <script async 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=loadMap">
     </script>
```

Comment: remove callback = loadmap form link

Comment: What is the error? Also, I don't think it is a good idea showing your api key

Comment: Thank you but the error still persists.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined This is the error and also the map does not show up

Comment: you are trying to use the `google` object before it is loaded. removed the async attribute and place the google reference above your javascript code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that 'Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined' because of this statement

```
var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.06368, 72.53135);
```

At the time of executing this ^ line of code, google is still not yet defined. I suggest to put that statement inside of your loadMap() function.

Check this working example: http://jsbin.com/lukexag/4/edit?html,css,js,output

Here is the code snippet:

```js
var map;
var circle;
var marker;
var currentlatlng;

function loadMap() {
    setLatLongValue();
    currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.06368, 72.53135);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 16,
        center: currentlatlng,
        mapTypeId: 'terrain',
        mapTypeControl: true,
        navigationControl: true
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: currentlatlng,
        draggable: true,
        map: map
    });
  
    marker.addListener('click', function(event) {
      drawCircle(event.latLng);
    });

    setLatLongValue();
    drawCircle();
}

function setLatLongValue() {
    // jQuery('#txtPointA1').val(currentlatlng.lat()); //#txtPointA1
    // jQuery('#txtPointA2').val(currentlatlng.lng());
}

function drawCircle() {

    var radius = 200;

    
    if (jQuery('#txtPointB1').val() !== '' && !isNaN(jQuery('#txtPointB1').val()) && parseInt(jQuery('#txtPointB1').val()) > 0) {
        radius = parseInt(jQuery('#txtPointB1').val());
    }
    jQuery('#txtPointB1').val(radius.toString());
   

    var options = {
        strokeColor: '#800000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#C64D45',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        map: map,
        center: currentlatlng,
        radius: radius
    };

    circle = new google.maps.Circle(options);
}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/jquery-3.2.1%20(2).js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCKQX3cyZ7pVKmBwE8wiowivW9qH62AVk8&callback=loadMap">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Update: Radius is now working

Comment: Thanks a lot @James it worked that error is not shown but the circle around the marker does not appear.

Comment: Check my updated code snippet. You can now see the Circle around your marker.

Comment: Got it just shifted the drawCircle method inside loadMap, and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Got it! Just shifted the drawCircle function inside loadMap, and it works perfectly fine. But in console it still does show drawCircle not defined. I tried you edited code too. Thanks a lot @James